# Unity/Bolt, IL2CPP - ломает игру на Андроид, но в редакторе Unity - работает отлично

Tags: c#, android, c++, unity3d, native

Создаю игру на **Unity** с помощью визуального программирования - **Bolt**. Если установить scripting backend - **IL2CPP** - игра в редакторе Unity - работает, но после билда на Андроид - не работают звуки, музыка, загрузка сцены при нажатии на кнопки. **Ошибок в Unity консоле не выдаёт** (development build, profiler - активны).[image: Визуальный скрипт кнопки Play] Выше - визуальный скрипт кнопки Play (coroutine - активен, "TransitionCircle" - объект который анимирует плавную смену сцены, переменная "Scene" = название сцены, указана верно). При использовании scripting backend - **Mono** - всё работает отлично, в редакторе и на андроид. **Mono** - не позволяет использовать ARM64. Нужен - **IL2CPP**. **Есть предложения для разрешения проблемы?**

Comment: Предлагаю не использовать Bolt.

Comment: Возможно, нужно выполнить Pre-Build: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/bolt-aot.html

Comment: ssa112112, Спасибо, это действительно решение проблемы. 3 Дня голову себе ломал, что только не пробовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Абсолютно точное решение от ssa112112.

> Нужно выполнить Pre-Build:
> [docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/bolt-aot.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/bolt-aot.html)